# What are / could be the applications of Delaunay oriented matroids?

Tags: hyperplane-arrangements, oriented-matroids

The Delaunay oriented matroid is studied in detail by [F. Santos](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02716807) (actually this paper is more general).

For a set of points $S$ (in any dimension), let $C$ be a sphere, $C^+$ be its interior, $C^-$ be its exterior, then $(S\cap C^+, S\cap C, S\cap C^-)$ is a covector of the Delaunay oriented matroid.  The fact that it's an oriented matroid can be seen by lifting the points to a paraboloid in the space with one dimension higher and then observing a hyperplane arrangement.

**Question**: How did / will Delaunay oriented matroid help understanding Delaunay triangulations?